# link_to popup modal div not working in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a rails app where I want to show a modal popup div whenever I click on link_to 'Add new Progress' 
I tried to do it but didn't work out well. Javascript gives no errors I don't know what to do. please help anyone

my code =  View file

```
.modal.fade#myModal
.mymodal-content
    My content goes here
#main_div_index.row.clearfix

    #index_sidebar_aims
        %h4=link_to 'I have a new AIM' ,{'class':'opener','data-toggle':"modal" ,'data-target':"#myModal"}
        %br
        %h4=link_to 'I made progress' , aims_path
#index_progress_div.col-md-6.col-xs-6.col-sm-6
    show feeds from :
```

my code = javascript

```
var open = $('.opener');
var modal = $('.mymodal');

 open.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display='show';
 }
```

my code css

```
.mymodal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

 /* Modal Content */
 .mymodal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe; }
```

Comment: Try changing `modal.style.display='show'` to `modal.style.display='block'`

Comment: not working, their is some problem in js only, I changed some of my code and tried to debug and then I came up with this js error that says = 'application.self-d159971….js?body=1:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined'

Comment: are your getting this error when clicked ?

Comment: I was , i solved that but still no div showing.. i tried putting an alert fn inside my fn to make sure function is called.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are already using jQuery. Try using jQuery to show modal on click;

```
var open = $('.opener');
var modal = $('.mymodal');

open.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.show()
})
```

Comment: the point is, when i changed link_to to a html button it worked

Comment: I want it to be link_to how can i make it work with a link_to so that i can show a form and redirect user to another page

Comment: Sorry I have zero experience with rails, what link_to currently renders into? h4 tag? it would still work with jQuery https://jsbin.com/xododij/edit?html,css,js,output . If you select an element with jQuery it returns a jQuery object and it don't have many native methods available, so you have to use jQuery for adding events.